# How to start app with metadata for with route to open?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to define what "screen" to open based on metadata sent to the app? Like, for example, from an app shortcut on Android/iOS? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible to do in pure Dart the current Flutter API. I would write a plugin that intercepts `application:openURL:options:` on iOS and `onCreate/onNewIntent` on Android. You can use your plugin to give the Dart code a way to access the native metadata you received, and use this to `push` a new `Route` onto your `Navigator` stack during startup. You can see something similar in the [firebase_messaging example app](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart#L123), which would be a good starting point for learning your way around the plugin system.

Here's the [documentation](https://flutter.io/platform-plugins/) on plugins for more information. If you do decide to write a plugin, consider publishing it so that others can use it as well.

You may also want to check out this [comment on issue 8711](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8711#issuecomment-304681212) which describes another team trying to add deep links to their Flutter app.